Sharing Subdomains Across Different Business Units
I have two Business Units in Salesforce Marketing Cloud. In one of them, I have landing pages set up on a specific subdomain. Is it possible to share this registered subdomain with another Business Unit so it can also use it? If yes, what steps do I need to take to achieve this? Do I need to involve SF support or I can do it in Account Settings?

You mean the SAP domain or the private domain?

@Duc Le I mean private domain

Request SF support to copy it to your BU. SAP domain or Private Domain can be shared across BUs

If you've set up an SAP domain in one business unit, you can request Salesforce support to make it available for other business units as well. SAP domains can be shared across multiple BUs. To do this, you'll need to create a support case, including the MIDs of the relevant business units and the original case number for the SAP configuration
Please refer the discussion: https://trailhead.salesforce.com/trailblazer-community/feed/0D54S00000PiyPYSAZ

I meant private domain
